# circular progressbar in GWT

Tags: gwt, gwt2, gwtp

I am not able to understand how to rotate the image.
I am trying to make circular progress bar.

I got a image grom [preloder](http://preloaders.net/).

but i didn't find any thing in CSS to rotate this image.

Do i have to take the 2 or 3 images of same preloader and use setVIsible()

Plz help me to underStand this .

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use setVisible etc. If you download the file as gif and include it as any image file, that should work. Conduct a simple test to test for yourself and understand what I mean: save the gif file on your system and then open it with any browser. You will see the loading animation without any code. Basically gif file itself will take care of animation, as per [specificatoin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_Interchange_Format#Animated_GIF)